# How can I use a method like z-index method in css in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Premium',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 50),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

[image]

As seen in the image, the premium text remains behind the container. I want to show this on the container.

Comment: change the children order

Comment: Yes, this works, but I want to learn if there is a concept like z-index in flutter.

Comment: `Stack` does not have such thing, however other (3rd party) widgets could implement it

Answer (score 0):

Flutter widget tree work as flow, so the order of your widget is important, so you need to change your stack child to get what you want:

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        margin:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 50),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        ),
      )
      Positioned(
        left: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
              child: const Text(
                'Premium',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```